# Regex to Find All Gmail Addresses With 2 Exceptions

Tags: regex

Admittedly, I'm not a pro at Regex, but I'm usually able to find my way to what I need. This one though is really stumping me. I've tried half a dozen ways.

I'm trying to find all instances of @gmail.com addresses, with the exception of 2 addresses.

The gmail domain search works like a charm:

```
(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(gmail.com))
```

It's creating an exception for **brett@gmail.com** and **smith@gmail.com** that's really giving me trouble. Any insight would be great.

Comment: How about just removing the matches later? Why complicate the pattern to not include certain matches - a list that could grow bigger in the future?

Comment: @degant, The issue is that I'm feeding the Regex into a program in order to redact out emails. Unfortunately the program only allows the redactions to be applied, but not selectively removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative lookaheads and word boundaries `\b` like this:

```
(?!smith@)(?!brett@)\b\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com
```

- Negative Lookaheads `(?!brett@)(?!smith@)` don't allow email address containing only `brett` and `smith`. *Note: Adding the word boundary at the end acts like a bit of a hack since it prevents the negative lookahead from restricting emails that have `brett` as a prefix in the username and contain more text such as `brett999` and `brett.doe` These are now accepted because of the word boundary after each word. Only a username containing just `brett` or `smith` is rejected*
- `\b\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)` matches the username which cannot be just `brett` or `smith` due to the previous conditions. It includes a word boundary `\b` to help the negative lookahead to work correctly

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZkp6H/3)

```
// Doesn't match
brett@gmail.com
smith@gmail.com

// Matches
brettt@gmail.com
bret.t@gmail.com
_brett@gmail.com
bretty@gmail.com
brett_@gmail.com
brett99@gmail.com
test@gmail.com
john_doe.77@gmail.com
```

**EDIT:** Fix as per @Paurian's comments. Good catch! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the word boundary that was eluding me. This worked like a charm.

Comment: You might also want to place the @ after your exclusive words so that they don't get excluded. I.E. (?!smith@\b)(?!brett@\b)\b\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com ... otherwise addresses like "smith.john@gmail.com" could return a false positive or strip out the front.

Comment: Thanks @Paurian Good catch! Then the `\b` could be removed from the words if they are followed by `@`

Answer (score 0):

If each email is on its own line, the following works for me:

```
^(?=.*?\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com)(?!^smith@|brett@).*$
```

Passes:

- jack@gmail.com
- fred@gmail.com
- jsmith@gmail.com
- dbrett@gmail.com
- smith.john@gmail.com
- brett_smith@gmail.com
- brett.smith@gmail.com

Fails:

- smith@gmail.com
- brett@gmail.com
- foo@groovy.com

Comment: This would filter out `smith.john@gmail.com`. Consider adding `@` into `(?!^(smith|brett)@)`.

Comment: Fails for `brett_smith@gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks! The look-ahead has been modified based on Dmitry's suggestion and now it's working.